# Removing a Numpy object from Python list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of (x, y) coordinates:

```
[[120.027954 167.9987  ]
 [918.95233  175.37206 ]
 [918.14026  540.6017  ]
 [113.1368   535.2902  ]]
```

I want to remove one row at a time:

```
centers = list(centers)

top_left = min(centers, key=sum)
print("top_left ", top_left)
centers.remove(top_left)

bottom_right = max(centers, key=sum)
print("bottom_right ", bottom_right)
centers.remove(bottom_right)
```

On the last line above, I get this error:

```
('top_left ', array([120.027954, 167.9987  ], dtype=float32))
('bottom_right ', array([918.14026, 540.6017 ], dtype=float32))    
centers.remove(bottom_right) 
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.
Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I don't know why centers.remove(top_left) works but not centers.remove(bottom_right)?

Comment: you provided inconsistent code`print("bottom_right ",` with output `('bottom_left ', `...

Comment: why dont you use pop with index as param..since centers is a list

Comment: It seems that your description is incomplete. Your lists are all of a sudden NumPy objects? Please post a minimal *complete and reproducible* example.

Comment: Since it is indeed the reason for the error, it would be best if you alter the title and description to explicitly state that you are removing an *NumPy object* from an *Python list*, so that other people with the same problem can find this answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python remove function is optimized to first check for identity check and then check for equality. So for `alist.remove(item)` first `item is alist[0]` is checked (identity check, looking for memory location) and then checking `item == alist[0]` (equality check, looking at the actual value(s))

For numpy arrays however, equality is overridden by numpy to return a per item check. (A vectorized check. `np.array([1, 2]) == np.array([2, 2])` returns `np.array([False, True])`.) This cannot be processed by the remove function, because it expects just a single boolean.

Identity still works for numpy arrays however. So for your first case, you were just lucky the exact element was the first element. For the second case, it had to check multiple elements, but the first time it checked for equality, after its initial identity check, it received a vector of booleans and failed throwing the "ambigious" error.

In your particular case, I would recommend extracting the index instead for your operations, and use pop afterwards.

```
ind = min(range(len(centers)), key=lambda ind: sum(centers[ind]))
```

For other people it is best to write a custom function with a loop checking for equality yourself instead of defaulting to the numpy equality function.

EDIT:

In this particular case another more performant solution is also possible using (optimized) built-in numpy functions.

```
summed_centers = centers.sum(axis=1)
mask = np.ones(len(summed_centers), np.bool_)
mask[[summed_centers.argmax(), summed_centers.argmin()]] = np.bool_(False)
new_centers = centers[mask]
```

EDIT2:

In case you didn't now, there is a `np.delete` function which can do the same but without explicitly making a mask array, but the documentation preferred the mask array, because `np.delete` always makes a copy of your data.

Comment: I was trying not do loop checking, but since Numpy array doesn't work with the remove function, I guess I don't have a choice! Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Comment: @AdamLee In your particular case I think you still don't have to loop. See my edit.